# What are the alternatives to throwing an exception in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling

I recently interviewed with a company for an internship. They asked me to write a recursive function to calculate factorial of a given integer. So I wrote something like this, on paper:

```
int factorial(int n){
    if(n<0){throw std::invalid_argument( "received negative value" );}
    if(n == 0){return 1;}
    else{
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

Then as a follow-up, they asked me questions along the lines of

> "What onus does throwing an exception put on the user of this function?"
>
> "Can you handle this in any other way?"
>
> "Can you handle it gracefully?"

I really didn't know what they were looking for/were hinting at. Can anyone tell me if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement to check for an exception requires the caller to trap and handle the exception, cluttering their code and also imposing a processing overhead to handling the exception.

There are some other ways you can return without raising an exception.

- The factorial of a number can't be zero or negative, so you can return 0 or a negative integer (i.e. a "magic number") to indicate that the factorial does not exist or could not be found. Similarly, if the input is too large to calculate a factorial within the range of an `int`, you can return this invalid value as well, or set the specific value to something that indicates the failure mode (e.g. 0 means input negative, -1 means input too large, -2 means any other exception).
- You can change your method signature to return a *pointer* to an `int`, and set the logic to return `NULL` to indicate no result (C code was classically filled with "check for null after the call to make sure it succeeded" logic). If you find the factorial, return a pointer to an `int` holding that value, created on the heap using `new`.
- You can accept a `short int` as the input parameter, eliminating many (but not all) input values whose factorial is too large to fit the return value. This won't fix things completely, but every bit helps. Combined with another method, you can reduce potential failure modes even further.

The first option above can be graceful, since it allows the caller to *consume* the value in many ways (e.g. printing it, using it in a further math operation) without feeding in something that is non-numeric or failing to have a number to deal with. The downside is that you can end up with a meaningless number. It's better in some contexts to output "Number of floors in building: -1, Cost: $-1" than to crash right in the middle of an important demo! A similar situation (invalid in terms of business rules but able to be processed data, in that case a pointer) produced the famous Minus World bug in Super Mario Bros.!

The last value is even more graceful, since it helps prevent invalid data from even *getting* to the function. As they say, Garbage In, Garbage Out.

Comment: And where exactly would the `int`, that's being pointed to, be? And how would that work in a multi-threaded program? And are you certain that this is the only error condition here (hint, it's not, there's at least one other obvious one)?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I responded. Those are the most obvious answers in a basic interview context. Of course you can find plenty more.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the OP said this was for an *internship*. This was not an uber-guru opportunity.

Comment: Basic error-handling concepts are nowhere near "uber-guru" territory.

Comment: Making the input parameter *unsigned* doesn't actually prevent invalid values entering the function. It actually makes them impossible to detect at runtime from within the function. It is perfectly possible to pass a negative value to an *unsigned* parameter and it will automatically be converted into a corresponding (but different) unsigned value. It means the calling code has to have pre-vetted the value before calling the function.

Comment: @RobertColumbia thank you for your answer. In fact, when I first wrote the code I just returned -1 for negative inputs. Later based on their questions, I changed it to throwing an exception!

The second and third options are new to me, maybe that's what they were looking for. Thanks everyone!